# Call a .ctp file from a layout file with CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp, layout

Is it possible to call a .ctp file from a layout which is also a .ctp file?

I have a default layout with the topbar, the footer and of course the variable $content_for_layout in the middle. I would like to dispatch the topbar and the footer into two others different .ctp files and I would like to call them from my layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1081/Elements).

```
<?php 
echo $this->element('topbar');
echo $content_for_layout;
echo $this->element('footer');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1081/Elements) or, in CakePHP 2.1, you can check out [blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks).